# Finding the biggest word

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Hello  I tryed converting a string to array and then finding the biggest word, output should be length of the word in numbers. Im not sure what im doing wrong and why this code is not working if someone could point it out for me I would be very grateful.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let words=str.split(" ");
  let bigword=0;
  
  for(let i=0; i<=words.length; i++) {
      if(words[i].length>bigword) {
          bigword=words[i].length;
      }
  }
  return bigword; 
}
```

Comment: Did you not see the error -> `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`  If your new to Javascript you will find the `console` very handy tool in debugging issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your loop runs longer than there is elements in array.

Change `i<=words.length` to `i<words.length`

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let words = str.split(" ");
  let bigword = 0;


  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    if (words[i].length > bigword) {
      bigword = words[i].length;
    }

  }
  
  return bigword;
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength('a aaa bb c'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, you are iterating a bit far away.
You can replace `i<= words.length` by `i< words.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Math.max` with passed mapped array of words lengths:

```js
const findLongest = (str) => {
  const words = str.split(' ');
  const longest = Math.max(...words.map(({ length }) => length));
  return longest;
};

const str = 'This is the test string';
const longestLength = findLongest(str);
console.log(longestLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
    let words = str.split(" ");
    let biglength = Math.max(...words.map(({ length }) => length));
    let word = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length == biglength) {
            word.push(words[i]);
        }
    }
    return word;
}
console.log(findLongestWordLength('a bb ccc ddd ee f'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findBigestWordLength(wordsParams) {
  const words = wordsParams.split(' ');

  console.log(Math.max(...words.map((word) => word.length)));
}

findBigestWordLength('a bb ccc dddd eeeee');
```